# pull comments from website comment box to my facebook business page timeline

Tags: facebook, comments

I have added the facebook comment box to a php page on my website. I am trying to import the posts and comments from my website comment box (or http://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?id=) to my facebook business timeline.

How can I do this? Is there any solution for that please?

I've tried adding a few different urls to the Canvas URL: in the app to see of I could get the comments showing in the namespace iframe and take it from there but was unsucessful.